# Find FIRST lowest value in table AND date on which that lowest value occurs

Tags: sql, postgresql

If I have a table with the following schema:

```
CREATE TABLE diet_watch (
  entry_date date NOT NULL,
  weight     double precision NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO diet_watch VALUES ('2001-01-01', 128.2);
INSERT INTO diet_watch VALUES ('2001-01-02', 121.0);
INSERT INTO diet_watch VALUES ('2001-01-03', 122.3);
INSERT INTO diet_watch VALUES ('2001-01-04', 303.7);
INSERT INTO diet_watch VALUES ('2001-01-05', 121.0);
INSERT INTO diet_watch VALUES ('2001-01-06', 128.0);
```

How would I write a query that would return the **FIRST** minimum weight between two dates **AND** the date on which the minimum weight occurs?

Ideally, this will be ANSI-SQL, i.e db agnostic. If I have to be forced to pick an SQL flavor, it will be PostgreSQL, since that is the db I am using.

**PSEUDO SQL:**

```
SELECT min(entry_date), min(weight)
FROM   diet_watch
where  entry date between date1 and date2
group  by entry_date;
```

Comment: It's hard to give you a correct answer if you keep changing the question!

Comment: @Gerrat: I corrected the question because I noticed that it did not accurately reflect the problem I was trying to solve. However, it was always the minimum weight I wanted (you can check the edits to the question). I noticed that the data I use can have multiple instances of minima values, so I modified the question to fetch the **FIRST** minimum and the date on which it occurs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Simple and fast solution:

```
SELECT weight, entry_date
FROM   diet_watch
WHERE  entry_date BETWEEN '2001-01-02' AND '2001-01-06'
ORDER  BY 1, 2
LIMIT  1;
```

Works in PostgreSQL or MySQL and possibly others (not in Oracle or MS SQL Server).

#### Standard SQL (SQL:2003):

```
SELECT weight, entry_date
FROM  (
    SELECT weight, entry_date
          ,row_number() OVER (ORDER BY weight, entry_date) AS rn
    FROM   diet_watch
    WHERE  entry_date between '2001-01-02' and '2001-01-06'
    ) AS x
WHERE rn = 1;
```

Not supported by RDBMS which do not implement window functions (like MySQL).

#### Standard SQL variant (SQL:2008):

```
SELECT weight, entry_date
FROM   diet_watch
WHERE  entry_date BETWEEN '2001-01-02' AND '2001-01-06'
ORDER  BY weight, entry_date
FETCH  FIRST 1 ROWS ONLY;
```

Only supported by few RDBMS - find a [list on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Select_%28SQL%29#FETCH_FIRST_clause).

The **only** RDBMS supporting all of these is PostgreSQL (v8.4 or later).

---

Addressing question in comment, I quote [the manual here about ORDER BY](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-select.html#SQL-ORDERBY):

> Each expression can be the name **or ordinal number** of an output column
> (SELECT list item), or it can be an arbitrary expression formed from
> input-column values.

Emphasis mine. It's just a syntactical shortcut, that is supported by a number of RDBMS. SQL Server is obviously not among them.

Comment: +1: Nice, short and sweet. SQL poetry. You saved my bacon (yet again!). I was secretly hoping you would show up. Your cheque is in the post :)

Comment: @HomunculusReticulli: You are probably aware that `LIMIT 1` is specific to PostgreSQL (or MySQL), `TOP 1` for SQL Server, `rownum` for Oracle .. [Wikipedia has a nice list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Select_%28SQL%29#Result_limits).

Comment: Don't you need to order by [weight]?

Comment: @Dmitriy: it is there: `order by 1,2`

Comment: I had this set up in SQL Server with BETWEEN '2001-01-01' AND '2001-01-06' and it gave me 128.2, instead of 121.0. Maybe it's just too late in a day; i might be off here... :)

Comment: @Dmitriy: I did. I added some explanation to the answer. SQL server does not understand this syntax and interprets `ORDER BY 1` as constant, which is just nonsensical noise in this place.

Comment: I see... So when you run below in Postgate, what result do you get, 121.0, or 128.2:SELECT weight, entry_date
FROM   diet_watch
WHERE  entry_date BETWEEN '2001-01-01' AND '2001-01-06'
ORDER  BY 1, 2
LIMIT  1;

Comment: @Dmitriy: I made my answer more complete, so I don't fool innocent bystanders. ;)

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter: Hmm, looks like my example is simpler than my real use case. In my use case, I also have a user_id in the table, and I want to find the FIRST lowest weight (and date) as before, but for every user. Could you please modify your answer - or should I ask a new question?

Comment: @HomunculusReticulli: I've put in some effort to provide a complete answer for the current state of the question. You should ask a new question. Else it's confusing people. It's also the general custom here: open a new question for a different question.

Comment: No problem. I was just about to say I think I figured it out http://sqlfiddle.com/#!1/7aa4e/13 - it may not be elegant but at least it works. thanks any how for your help originally - that got me thinking along the right lines.

Comment: @HomunculusReticulli: I am afraid the query in your sqlfiddle is incorrect. You get the wrong date with your minimum weight. Post a new question, you will get an answer quickly. I know I have one: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!1/7aa4e/14 BTW, there is something wrong with sqlfiddle. date is output as formatted timestamp.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT min(entry_date), min(weight) from diet_watch where weight = (
    SELECT MIN(weight) as wt from diet_watch where entry_date between date1 and date2
) and entry_date between date1 and date2
```

[**EDIT**: Answer tweaked slightly, as it appears that the question was changed from finding the weight at the minimum date to the date at the minimum weight]

Also, the question asks for the "FIRST" minimum weight...which I'll assume means the earliest date with the minimum weight.

Comment: You need to repeat `where entry_date between date1 and date2` in the outer SELECT with this query or it can yield incorrect results.

Answer (score 0):

You might request a SELECT * ORDER BY weight ASC LIMIT 1 (most DBs support LIMIT), or not use LIMIT at all and just retrieve the first row from the cursor.

Otherwise, you need a JOIN to get the minimum and then retrieve the date when the minimum did occur; and in case of multiple dates wherein the minimum was attained, you would still require LIMIT and/or a single fetch.

Answer (score 0):

Working from Gerrat's answer, could just order by entry_date and grab the top row.

```
SELECT top 1 entry_date, weight
FROM diet_watch
WHERE weight = (SELECT MIN(weight) as wt from diet_watch)
ORDER BY entry_date
```

EDIT: This is SQL Server code.  You could use whatever the equivalent in postgre is, though.